# Having trouble grasping the Implicit function theorem and its applications

Tags: multivariable-calculus, implicit-function-theorem

I'm trying to wrap my head around this theorem. I'd really appreciate if you can help me with this exercise and my pathetic attemp at solving it. (I'd also accept tips on how to approach these kinds of exercises in general.)

> Consider the equation:
>   $$(x+1)^2 - 3\cos y + \cos xz + \ln (x^2y^4 + 1) + e^{\sin z} - 3 = 0$$
>   **(1)** Prove that there's a neighborhood $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ of the point $(0,\pi/2)$ and an interval $I \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, $I=(\pi - \epsilon, \pi + \epsilon)$ such that the equation given defines implicitly a $C^1$ function $z=g(x,y): U \to I$.
>
> **(2)** Find $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(0,\pi/2)$

I was taught to first consider the relevant level surface:

$$S=\{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : f(x,y,z) = (x+1)^2 - 3\cos y + \cos xz + \ln (x^2y^4 + 1) + e^{\sin z} - 3 = 0 \}$$

**(My textbook speaks indistinctly of "equations" and "functions", but isn't the point of the theorem to determine when an equation defines a function? E.g., why would it be legitimate to assume a priori that $f(x,y,z)$ defines a function?)**

Moving on, we know that

$$f(0,\pi/2,z) = e^{\sin z} - 1 = 0 \ \iff \ \sin z = 0$$

In particular, $(0,\pi/2, \pi) \in S$. We also know that $f$ is $C^1$ (because it's sum, composition, etc. of $C^1$ functions) and that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}(0,\pi/2, \pi) = -1 \neq 0$.

Therefore the Implicit function theorem guarantees that there's an open disk $B \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, an open neighborhood $V \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ of the point $(0,\pi/2,\pi)$ and a $C^1$ function $\phi: B\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $S \cap V = \text{Graph}(\phi)$. **How can i get from this $\phi$ to the $g$ that I need to prove exists? They exist in different vector spaces, right?**

---

Moving on to $(2)$...

$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(0,\pi/2) = \frac{- \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}|_{(0,\pi/2, g(0,\pi/2))}}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}|_{(0,\pi/2, g(0,\pi/2))}} = 2$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you made a typo or it's a genuine mistake, but the Implicit Function Theorem guarantees that there exists an open set $B \subseteq \Bbb{R}^2$ containing the point $(0,\pi/2)$, and an open set $V \subseteq \Bbb{R}^3$ containing $(0, \pi/2, \pi)$, and a $C^1$ function $\phi: B \to \Bbb{R}$, such that
\begin{equation}
S \cap V = \text{Graph}(\phi)
\end{equation}
So the function $\phi$ is actually the function $g$ that you seek.

By the way, I didn't verify your computations with the numbers, but the formula you used to compute the partial derivative is right.

Also, I'm not entirely sure what your initial concern regarding the use of terms "equation" and "function" is about. There are several equivalent ways of stating the IFT, but one way is to say that it is a criterion for checking when the level set of a $C^1$ function $f$ can locally be expressed as the graph of a $C^1$ function $g$. Also, we are not assuming a priori that your given function $f$ implicitly defines a function $g$ defined on a neighbourhood $U$ of $(0,\pi/2)$; this is something which has to be proven, and you have in fact proven it.

Comment: @ydnfmew Notice how I specifically used the words "is a criterion for checking..." i.e there are certain conditions which have to be satisfied before you can conclude that the equation actually (locally) defines a function. So yes, you're right it is possible for an equation containing $x,y,z$ to not implicitly define a function; but the point of the theorem is that if enough "nice" conditions are satisfied, then locally, the equation defines an implicit function.

Comment: Sorry couldn't edit the last one.

Comment: > It is a criterion for checking when the level set of a $C^1$ function $f$ can locally be expressed as the graph of a $C^1$ function $g$

What confuses me is this: many exercises start with an equation $a = b$ (e.g. containing variables $x,y,z$) and ask you to express one variable as a function of the others. The first step then is to focus on the level set $S = \{ f(x,y,z) = a - b = 0 \}$. But why are we authorized to say that? Is it possible for an equation containing variables $x,y,z$ not to define any function at all (for any of pair of variables whatsoever)?

Comment: What do you mean by "why are we authorised to say that"? We usually consider the zero level set of the function $f$, so that we can apply the IFT to it. I'm sorry I don't really understand your concern. We just want to rewrite our given information in a format so that we can apply the theorem we know. For instance, take the unit circle in $\Bbb{R}^2$, given by $x^2 + y^2 = 1$. We can see without any calculus that if $(a,b)$ lies on the circle, and $a \neq \pm1$, thenwe can solve $y$ as a function of $x$ ($\pm \sqrt{1-x^2}$, with $+$ if $b>0$ and $-$ if $b<0$).

Comment: We can also apply the IFT to this situation: define the function $f: \Bbb{R}^2 \to \Bbb{R}$ by $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2 -1$. Now, consider the level set $S= f^{-1}\{0\}$. The IFT now tells you that if $(a,b) \in S$ and $a \neq \pm1$, then we can find a unique $C^1$ function $g: U \subset \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$, where $U$ is an open set containing $a$, and such that for every $x \in U$, $f(x,g(x)) = 0$. i.e we "solved" $y$ as a function of $x$. Equivalently,there's a neighbourhood $V \subset \Bbb{R}^2$ of $(a,b)$ such that $S \cap V = \text{graph}(g)$.